# Ui Component: listening to event of other component

Tags: magento2, checkout, uicomponent

I have a custom ui component that generates a custom form as part of the checkout (payment section). This form contains two required input fields that need to be filled before an order can be placed.

I would like to react to the click of a "place order" button of the payment methods. It should trigger a validation and display an error message if those inputs are not filled.

How would I do this from inside my own ui component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out adobe is providing an answer: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/add-order-validation/